# Replace XML Node value with another Classic ASP, VB script

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the following XML that need to parsed using ASP VBscript,

```
<ERROR>
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>X11</CODE> 
        <TEXT>E112</TEXT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>X14</CODE> 
        <TEXT>E888</TEXT> 
    </ITEM>
    <OTHER-INFO>
        <XID>I989</XID>  
    <OTHER-INFO>    
<ERROR>
```

My requirement is to replace TEXT value inside ITEM with its corresponding detailed information that I will get it  from getInfo(code) function. How to replace TEXT value using classic asp and vbscript.

output required,

```
<ITEM>
    <CODE>X11</CODE> 
        <TEXT>Detailed Explanation about this error</CODE>
</ITEM>
```

I have written the following code to iterate through each ITEM.
objMSXML contains the above tags and i need the results back in the same object.

```
If objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("ERROR").length <> 0 Then
    For Each ObjNode In objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("ITEM")
        strTrasMsg = getInfo(objECGO.xVal("CODE",ObjNode,"STR"))


    Next
End If
```

Comment: "<TEXT>E112</CODE>" is not well-formed XML; not closed: not closed: ERROR, OTHER-INFO, OTHER-INFO, ERROR.

Comment: Sorry Ekkehard, i have updated the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using xpath to select node and replace the text

something like, I did not tried this but it should work, as xpath is supported

```
   Set Node = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode("//ERROR/ITEM[../CODE/text()="item code vlaue"/text)

   Node.text = "NEW VALUE"

   xmldoc.save
```

Or another approach would be recreating the response by writing tags, as you already populated the code and description like.

```
var myxml = "<ITEM><CODE>"your value"</CODE><TEXT>"your value"</CODE></ITEM>
```

something than save back this xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (assumes a TEXT element does exist for each ITEM).

```
For Each oItem In objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("ITEM") 
    oItem.selectSingleNode("TEXT").text = getInfo(objECGO.xVal("CODE", oItem ,"STR"))  
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
For Each ObjNode In objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("ITEM")
    strTrasMsg = "whatever-" & ObjNode.firstChild.text ' getInfo(objECGO.xVal("CODE",ObjNode,"STR"))
    WScript.Echo strTrasMsg, ObjNode.childNodes(1).text
    ObjNode.childNodes(1).text = strTrasMsg
Next
```

that is: use the DOM tree and access child nodes by index.

Long answer:

If you (all) present your "edit my xml"-problems according to this skeleton:

```
  Dim sXml : sXml = Join(Array(_
       "<ERROR>" _
    ,  "    <ITEM>" _
    ,  "        <CODE>X11</CODE>" _
    ,  "        <TEXT>E112</TEXT>" _
    ,  "    </ITEM>" _
    ,  "    <ITEM>" _
    ,  "        <CODE>X14</CODE>" _
    ,  "        <TEXT>E888</TEXT>" _
    ,  "    </ITEM>" _
    ,  "    <OTHER-INFO>" _
    ,  "        <XID>I989</XID>" _
    ,  "    </OTHER-INFO>" _
    ,  "</ERROR>" _
  ))
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.loadXml sXml

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     If objMSXML.getElementsByTagName("ERROR").length <> 0 Then
        Dim ObjNode, strTrasMsg
        For Each ObjNode In objMSXML.documentElement.selectNodes("ITEM")
            strTrasMsg = "whatever-" & ObjNode.firstChild.text '             
            ---- problem -----
        Next
        WScript.Echo objMSXML.xml
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
whatever-X11 E112
whatever-X14 E888
<ERROR>
        <ITEM>
                <CODE>X11</CODE>
                <TEXT>whatever-X11</TEXT>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
                <CODE>X14</CODE>
                <TEXT>whatever-X14</TEXT>
        </ITEM>
        <OTHER-INFO>
                <XID>I989</XID>
        </OTHER-INFO>
</ERROR>
```

trivial problems of well-formness and validity could be solved before posting and solutions would flock in much faster.